# At what time and where I can find shared jeeps in New Jalpaiguri to Darjeeling

Tags: india, transportation, night-transport

I need to get to Darjeeling from New Jalpaiguri. As I know there are two main options: private taxi and shared jeeps. If it is possible I would like to use shared jeeps.

I will be in New Jalpaiguri around 16:00 (in November). Is it possible to get the shared jeep at this time ? At what time they close / stops working ?

And where exactly I can find them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, they're available. Private taxis are easily available during that time and so are shared ones.

**Private Taxis**

There are plenty of private taxis available both outside the NJP (New Jalpaiguri) railway station and Bagdogra airport. Negotiate the rates and drop point prior to boarding the vehicle, it is advisable to take one from the Pre-Paid taxi counters. Usually takes about 3hrs to reach Darjeeling.

**Shared Jeeps**

There are two places from where you will get shared jeeps for Darjeeling - Outside NJP(New Jalpaiguri) Station and next to Siliguri Main Bus Stand. Shared jeeps have 10seats and you'll have to wait until all of them are occupied, which can stretch up to 30-45min in low seasons. Shared Jeep fare is around 150rs from NJP and 130rs from Siliguri Bus Stand up to Darjeeling. Takes about 3.5 to 4hrs

Remember the taxis will drop you at Darjeeling town center (i.e. either at the Chowk Bazaar stand or at Clubside Taxi stand next to Gandhi Road police point).

Comment: Thanks, I know it. I just want to know, at what time shared jeeps stop working ?

Comment: There's no fix timing, but I've seen some have a go at around 8pm as well. Mostly it depends on drivers

Comment: You're welcome, but it is highly suggested that you complete your journey during the daylight.

Comment: Before 18:30-19:00 in November. Right ?

Comment: Yeah, no worries :)